# ns2 global variable

Tags: ns2, otcl

I have created variable using loop like that:

```
   for {set i 0} {$i<5} {incr i} {
        set n($i) [$ns node]
   }
```

How to call n($i) variable by some procedure? I call it as

```
global n(0) n(1) n(2) n(3) n(4)
```

But I got the error :

ns: record: bad variable name "n(0)": upvar won't create a scalar variable that looks like an array element
    while executing

Answer (score 0):

I figured out : 
 
`global n` 
 
is enough to call array variable n.